# Facebook Android openActiveSessionWithPublishPermissions analog

Tags: android, facebook, single-sign-on

I am porting ios code to android and I have `openActiveSessionWithPublishPermissions` method.

Is there anything similar in android ?

Or only way is to call `openActiveSession` and `openForPublish`

The main problem is that the user will have to say OK twice. I would like to show dialog once if possible.